# How do you edit a stack of polygons simultaneously?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon, editing

Using ArcMap 10.1.
Lets say you have 100 polygons that all are in the exact same shape and in the exact same place.  They appear to be one polygon.  How would you edit the shape of all 100 at the same time, can you share vertices among the 100 polygons?  Can you join all 100 and keep their separate attributes and Object ID's?

Comment: What software are you using?  What format are you storing the polygons in?

Comment: ESRI ArcMap 10.1, I have them in a Geodatabase.  Feature Class, Polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try [Editing shared geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000001m000000) and [Reshaping a topology edge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm00000013000000). (Also #10 [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/08/17/getting-the-most-out-of-editing-in-arcgis-10-part-2/))

Comment: ESRI ArcMap 10.1, I have them in a Geodatabase.

Comment: None of the polygons are Topology.  They are in a geodatabase, feature class, polygon.

Comment: Are you talking about duplicate polygons that you want to  remove it ?

Comment: Map topology can be based on any feature classes. You need to create topology manually for your polygons, read this [Creating a map topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_map_topology/01mm0000000r000000/)

Comment: After playing with the Topology tool, I am amazed that I haven't used this before.  This is what I was looking for dealing with stacked polygons!  Thanks nadya